# Adding black pixels, squaring and resizing image

Tags: python, scikit-image

I have some images which have different sizes.
I would like to do the following:

1. Read in the image.
2. Square the image by adding black pixels in such a way that the image with the black pixels takes as height and width the bigger value of the both and the original image is in the center and the pixels are equally distributed below or upon (on the left/ right) the image.
3. Resize the image to 224, 224.

So, graphically the process I would like to code looks as follows:

[image: Image process]

I coded the steps 1 and 3, but regarding step 2 I am stumbling:

```
file_name = "/path/to/image.png"
img = imread(file_name)
#Squaring, adding black pixel, center the image

img = resize(img, (224, 224))
```

Answer (score 0):

To perform step 2 you could 'pad' the image with values which equal 0 (black) and this is how I would do it:

'''

```
img = cv2.imread("image.png")

if img.shape[0] != 224:
    img = cv2.resize(img, (224, img.shape[1]))

if img.shape[0] < 224:
    padding_y = (224-img.shape[0])/2
    padded_img = np.pad(img[:,:,2], ((int(padding_y),int(padding_y)),(0,0)), mode='constant', constant_values=0)
else:
    print("Y dimension is bigger than 224 pixels")
```

'''

So first I check the shape of the image and if the x axis is not equal to the desired size (224), it is resized. Then I check if the Y axis is lower than our desired size (again 224), if it less, we determine by how much and devide this value by 2, and this padding_y variable will be the size of the padding above and below our image. Finally, we use the numpy package to add padding to the image with the padding be black (constant_values=0).

Please note that this approach assumes that the Y axis will always be less than 224.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I get several errors because variables are not defined, as `resized_img` or `padding_y`

Comment: Hi there, I have modified the answer and it should work. Note that if the images Y dimension is bigger than 224, no padding will occur and the print message will be displayed. I hope it helps.

Comment: Does this answer solve your problem? if it does you could close the question.

Answer (score 0):

To add black pixel at the borders it was more straight forward for me to use cv2.copyMakeBorder() instead of numpy.pad. Here is a useful tutorial: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/df2/tutorial_py_basic_ops.html